# Harder-Than-It-Seems: Finding inverse of $f(x)=x^3-x-12$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, cubics

This may seem simple, but I have had long days of frustration with finding the inverse of the function

$$f(x)=x^3-x-12.$$

I got this on some homework and it did not ask for the inverse. However I wanted to try anyways. So this is as far as  I got:

$$x=y^3-y-12$$
$$x+12=y^3-y$$
$$y(y^2-1)=x+12$$
$$y(y+1)(y-1)=x+12.$$

And that is absolutely as far as I go. In the end, I have no idea how this turns out to be the answer:

[image]

A step-by-step walk-through in finding the inverse is gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Solving a cubic equation to get the inverse is not so straight forward as in the quadratic case. You can look at the wiki article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots - go to the section on special cases and you'll see that your equation can be treated that way - the formula gives a result very much like your result from matlab.  If your equation doesn't have 'simple' roots then I'm afraid this is the ugly reality. If you slog it all out, you should be able to verify that the inverse is correct by substituting it into the original equation.

Comment: Search for solving a depressed cubic equation. You will find in several places a description of the type of step-by-step process you seek.

Comment: Your effort at factoring $y^3-y$ doesn't help.  It is rare that factoring things not equal to zero helps, but your try is correct. It often helps if you are looking for solutions in the integers instead of the reals.  You just need to solve $y^3-y-(12+x)=0$ using [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method)  It is a mess.

Comment: Note that this function is not one-to-one. Indeed, it's inverse in some cases has *three* values, which makes the formula necessarily complicated.

Comment: For an actually _impossible_ inverse, try $y=2^xx$. The inverse can't be written down in terms of the standard functions you know about.

Answer (score 3):

There are two classic ways of solving cubics.

- A magical Tartaglia way:

  Let $y = u + v$. Then the equation becomes $u^3 + 3uv(u+v) + v^3 - (u + v) = x+12$. Since the choice of $u$ and $v$ is so far arbitrary, we may let $3uv=1$, which cancels two of the terms leaving $u^3 + v^3 = x+12$, and because we let $3uv=1$ it *also* results in $u^3 + \frac{1}{(3u)^3} = x+12$.

  The latter is a quadratic equation for $u^3$.
- A "modern" Vieta way is based on the fact that $$\cos 3x = 4\cos^3x - 3 \cos{x} = 3(\frac{4}{3}\cos^3x - \cos{x})$$

  Scale $y = \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}} z$, so that $y^3 - y = \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}(\frac{4}{3}z^3 - z)$ and let $z = \cos \theta$. It gives $$\cos{3\theta} = 3\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}(x + 12)$$

Answer (score 0):

Finding the inverse of function f(x) is effectively solving the equation f(x)= y.  There exist a "cubic formula" which can be used to solve such an equation but it is very complicated as you can see from the "inverse" you were given.

Comment: I guess the cubic equation has a formula for solving for x, its a bit more complicated than the quadratic, but you can plug in the values for the coefficients and punch out the result for x ( remember there might be more than one x and you have to consider if each solution is valid for your problem). I guess the process is similar to solving a quadratic, just the answer is a little messy.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a remark regarding your question. To make the answer seem more related to the question, I will remark that the answer to your question for the general cubic equation is [here](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/).

I'll note here, and this may be of some interest to you, that there is a similar equation for roots of quartic equations (equations of degree $4$), see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots). However, there is no solution for polynomials of degree $\geq 5$. This is because the symmetric group $S_n$ is not solvable if $n\geq 5$; this result is called Abel's theorem. This does not state, however, that some polynomials of degree $\geq 5$ have no solution (this would contradict the fundamental theorem of algebra which states that the field $\mathbf{C}$ is algebraically closed). The proof of this result can be done using Galois theory.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse function $y(x)$ satisfies $x=y^3-y-12$, or the cubic equation

$$y^3-y-(x+12)=0$$
Use Cardano’s formula to obtain

$$y(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac {x+12}2+\sqrt{\frac{(x+12)^2}4-\frac1{27}}} +\sqrt[3]{\frac {x+12}2-\sqrt{\frac{(x+12)^2}4-\frac1{27}}}
$$